# how to create same name submit in flask-wtf?

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms

i want to create two same name submit in html like this

```
<input type="submit" name="key" value="up">
<input type="submit" name="key" value="down">
```

but i want to use flask-wtf to do it, i don't know how to create Class?is like this?

```
class NameForm(FlaskForm):
    submit = SubmitField('up')
    submit = SubmitField('down')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Doing it like that will simply overwrite the class attribute `submit`. Do it like this:

```
class NameForm(FlaskForm):
    key = SubmitField('not_used_string')
```

Then in your html after `return render_template('page.html', form=form)` you render it like this:

```
{{ form.key(value='up', id="A1") }}  # -> will render <input id="A1" name="key" type="submit" value="up">
{{ form.key(value='down', id="A2") }} # -> will render <input id="A2" name="key" type="submit" value="down">
```

You don't have to supply id's but if you don't they will both be `key`.

Note that in order to have the same `name` you can only have one class attribute with that name.